# Not able to create alert dialog with rounded corners..things I tried

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

[image]

**dialog_border.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>

    <stroke android:color="@color/yellow"
            android:width="5dp"/>
    <padding android:bottom="10dp"
             android:left="10dp"
             android:right="10dp"
             android:top="10dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="25dp"/>
```

In my custom dialog layout,I have set background to `android:background="@drawable/dialog_border"`

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this,  AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT).create();

 alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 alertDialog.setView(alertDialogView); 
 alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to draw the shape in the layout file you're using. Using `isVisible="gone"` at startup. Then, when you want to show the dialog, you just show the Layout in which it is. The Button.onClickListener should just Hide the Layout again.

Something like:

```
<MainLayout> 
 ...
   <LinearLayout id="@+id/toHide" visibility="gone">
     <EditText>
     <Button id="@+id/closeDialog">
   </LinearLayout>
  ...
</MainLayout>
```

in your layout file. and then in your java file:

```
LinearLayout toHide = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.toHide);
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closeDialog);
btn.setOnClickListener( ... toHide.setVisibility(GONE); ...)
```

plus:

```
toHide.setVisibility(VISIBLE)
```

when you're showing your dialog

Answer (score 0):

The THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT might have a background tint that overrides the transparent color. Try using a custom style like this one:

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```